# Removing header in a dataset matlab after reading it

Tags: matlab

I am trying to remove the header (strings) from a table after reading the values from a CSV file into the table. Is there any way to remove the headers after reading into the table in matlab?

**EDIT**

I am reading from a csv file using this command

```
dataset('File','dataset.csv','Delimiter',',')
```

and it copies the headers (which i use in the beginning) but i now want to remove the header

Comment: So you are reading from what format?  It sounds like you are translating, right?  Are you using "fgetl" and "textscan"?

Comment: i am reading from a csv file using this command dataset('File','dataset.csv','Delimiter',',') and it copies the headers (which i use in the beginning) but i now want to remove the header

Comment: You can read it via "xlsread", but the data will be homogenous.  The numeric data will be in numeric spreadsheet, and the text in a different array.  What can you tell me about the nature of the data?  Is it homogenous or heterogenous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change the headers of a dataset, can be found via `help dataset`.

Example of making the variable names blank:

```
   load hospital
   % Access and modify metadata
   hospital.Properties.VarNames{1}='a'
```

Note that you cannot remove all varnames, or have multiple variables with the same name.
If you don't want variable names, consider using a cell array rather than a dataset.

---

Also note this comment in the help (for recent versions):

> The dataset data type might be removed in a future release. To work
>   with heterogeneous data, use the MATLAB® table data type instead. See
>   MATLAB table documentation for more information.